# The report drew a grim picture of inefficiency and corruption. What is "of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

> The report drew a grim picture of inefficiency and corruption.

"of" has a lot of usages including the meaning of "a part": a part of something.  What does it mean in this sentence?

Comment: Here "of " indicating the direction of the report which has been drawn about  inefficiency and corruption.

Comment: You know what 'a picture of something' means?

Comment: why "of" has lots of meanings: it's just "of". That's why Enlgish is myterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A meaning of *of* is synonymous with "which contains", but *of* works far better when words like "picture" are being used figuratively.

> The report drew a grim picture of inefficiency and corruption.

is roughly the same as saying

> The report drew a grim picture which contains inefficiency and corruption

though if you actually said "picture which contains" the reader/listener would likely think you are trying to say there is a real picture somewhere.